# rest_framework authtoken migration error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Unable to complete migration for rest_framework.authtoken

> Running migrations for authtoken:
>    - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
>   authtoken:0001_initial
>   FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: ALTER TABLE "authtoken_token" ADD CONSTRAINT "user_id_refs_id_14b35167" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "users_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
>   Error in migration: authtoken:0001_initial
>   DatabaseError: relation "users_user" does not exist

Using version djangorestframework-2.3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the custom user table name the migration isn't happening. Go to the initial migration and specify your user table using `db_table` in the migration where the code is trying to access your custom table. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

are you using  a custom user model?

if this was the case the
migration code for the app implementing the user model should look like:

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):
    needed_by = (
        ('oauthtoken', '0001_initial'),
    )
```